# Lumen App authentication

Tags: android, ios, security, ionic-framework, lumen

I am building an App API in Lumen, and I am a bit confused about how to lock down what/who can make requests to it.

At present I have no way of authenticating requests from the app, so anyone who knows the link could make requests from a browser and potentially cause havok. I know in the .env file there is an appkey variable which is currently empty, and after some research I can't seem to find a clear answer on what it actually does and if I need it.

So basically:

- If request comes from my app, proceed.
- If it comes from anything else, stop it.

That is what I am looking for.

I am using Ionic $http to make the requests.
Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Key is used for encryption which you can read at https://laravel.com/

use below command to generate key

```
 php artisan key:generate
```

For more info on lumen auth check below github, Lumen 5.3 token auth

[github link for lumen token auth](https://github.com/ishwarkatwe/lumen-api)